# Intl.NumberFormat with maximumFractionDigits

Tags: javascript

I was trying to format a number in Javascript with the `Intl.NumberFormat` function.
I create a new number formatter with the maximumFractionDigits of 20.

```
var formatter = Intl.NumberFormat(undefined,{maximumFractionDigits:20});
```

If i format numbers with this formatter the maximum number of fraction digits isn't 20.
e.g: `formatter.format(1.123456789)` result: "1.123456789"
**Works as expected.**

`formatter.format(1.123456789123456)` result: "1.12345678912346"
**In this case the number has 15 fraction digits, the formatted string has only 14. I don't understand that result.**
It's the same result for chrome firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point.

The maximum number of decimals is 17, but floating point arithmetic is not always 100% accurate.

Refer this [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i did another test and found out, that 1.123456789123456.toString() works as expected. That still confuses me.

Comment: Yes, String this is fine. Problem on Floating-Point